# Convert HTML web app table to PDF using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

every one I have HTML web app where I have converted Spreadsheet to HTML table now I would like to convert this HTML web app Table to PDF. How can this be accomplished?

Here is my Code

index.html

```
  <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
   function drawTable() {
   var query = new google.visualization.Query(
     'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5kqFmt1yclKVDdasujf-
  moxjX3QOVsyDyP7DIcF2u0/edit#gid=0');

  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
   if (response.isError()) {
     alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + 
  response.getDetailedMessage());
     return;
 }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
  var table = new 
  google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
 var options = {'title':'Bass Naming',
                  'width':'600',
                  'height':'400'};


   table.draw(data, options);
   var tabUri = table.getLinkUrl();

    }  

  </script>

  <title>Data from a Spreadsheet</title>
   </head>

  <body>
   <div>My Sheet</div>
  <div id="table_div"></div>
 <div>
  <h3> click here the below button to send the Table as PDF to mail :</h3>
   <button id='mail' onclick="myFunction()">Send to Mail</button>  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

code.gs

```
 function doGet(e) {
   return HtmlService
  .createTemplateFromFile("index")
   .evaluate()
  .setTitle("Charts for Rent Analyser")
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

[image: This is my Screen Short of my current Page]

Comment: Why do you create a second question for what seems to be the same question ? ( Possible duplicate with [Convert html table to pdf using google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072142/convert-html-table-to-pdf-using-google-app-script) )

Comment: Yes **No one is responding for my previous Question**  i thought the question was **not clear** so i made it clear that what i need exactly @Pierre-Marie Richard

Comment: Then you should considering just edit yyour previous question, or delete it, to avoid duplicate.

Comment: i Have Deleted my Previous Post Thank you, any Suggestion Regarding this solution Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below function in code.gs to mail the table as PDF attachment.

```
function exportAsPdf(submittedBy) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get('1w5kqFmt1yclKVDdasujf-moxjX3QOVsyDyP7DIcF2u0');
  var url = file.exportLinks['application/pdf'];
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

 MailApp.sendEmail({ 
      to:Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      subject:"Charts for Rent Analyser",
      htmlBody: "PFA",
      attachments:[response.getBlob().setName("Charts for Rent Analyser.pdf")],
     });  
}
```

Also make sure you enable the Drive services from "**Advanced Google Service**" and also the Drive API from "**Goolge API Console**".

Refer the below link for detailed code.

[Google App Script](https://script.google.com/d/1BmrVgNDvAczmu5UH_uCwfeJMfamyC2oDAOZJrQtubpo_hNEb9xdyT0WL/edit?usp=sharing)

[Exec Link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxAEpnSUg9tx8wPpwR4bNlbB1UI--_aTELw72mjwfrnBl6wsgk/exec)

Comment: Dear Ritz,Thank your for your code .With this am able to get the whole excel is converting in to pdf but i want to convert only the HTML table to be converted in to PDF

Comment: What is the difference between the HTML table and spreadsheet columns?